# How to use drain event of stream.Writable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

In Node.js I'm using the `fs.createWriteStream` method to append data to a local file. In the Node documentation they mention the `drain` event when using `fs.createWriteStream`, but I don't understand it.

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('fileName.txt');
var result = stream.write(data);
```

In the code above, how can I use the drain event? Is the event used properly below?

```
var data = 'this is my data';
if (!streamExists) {
  var stream = fs.createWriteStream('fileName.txt');
}

var result = stream.write(data);
if (!result) {
  stream.once('drain', function() {
    stream.write(data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 38):

The `drain` event is for when a writable stream's internal buffer has been emptied.

This can only happen when the size of the internal buffer once exceeded its `highWaterMark` property, which is the maximum bytes of data that can be stored inside a writable stream's internal buffer until it stops reading from the data source.

The cause of something like this can be due to setups that involve reading a data source from one stream faster than it can be written to another resource. For example, take two streams:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var read = fs.createReadStream('./read');
var write = fs.createWriteStream('./write');
```

Now imagine that the file `read` is on a SSD and can read at 500MB/s and `write` is on a HDD that can only write at `150MB/s`. The write stream will not be able to keep up, and will start storing data in the internal buffer. Once the buffer has reached the `highWaterMark`, which is by default 16KB, the writes will start returning `false`, and the stream will internally queue a drain. Once the internal buffer's length is 0, then the `drain` event is fired.

This is how a drain works:

```
if (state.length === 0 && state.needDrain) {
  state.needDrain = false;
  stream.emit('drain');
}
```

And these are the prerequisites for a drain which are part of the `writeOrBuffer` function:

```
var ret = state.length < state.highWaterMark;
state.needDrain = !ret;
```

---

To see how the `drain` event is used, take the example from the Node.js documentation.

```
function writeOneMillionTimes(writer, data, encoding, callback) {
  var i = 1000000;
  write();
  function write() {
    var ok = true;
    do {
      i -= 1;
      if (i === 0) {
        // last time!
        writer.write(data, encoding, callback);
      } else {
        // see if we should continue, or wait
        // don't pass the callback, because we're not done yet.
        ok = writer.write(data, encoding);
      }
    } while (i > 0 && ok);
    if (i > 0) {
      // had to stop early!
      // write some more once it drains
      writer.once('drain', write);
    }
  }
}
```

The function's objective is to write 1,000,000 times to a writable stream. What happens is a variable `ok` is set to true, and a loop only executes when `ok` is true. For each loop iteration, the value of `ok` is set to the value of `stream.write()`, which will return false if a `drain` is required. If `ok` becomes false, then the event handler for `drain` waits, and on fire, resumes the writing.

---

Regarding your code specifically, you don't need to use the `drain` event because you are writing only once right after opening your stream. Since you have not yet written anything to the stream, the internal buffer is empty, and you would have to be writing at least 16KB in chunks in order for the `drain` event to fire. The `drain` event is for writing many times with more data than the `highWaterMark` setting of your writable stream.

Comment: i'm doing more writes for same streams again and again .For example i have mentioned my code like that.my data value may be huge sometimes.

Comment: In your example you write once. Please show how you're actually writing things to the stream because writing a string once will never need the `drain` event.

Comment: updated my question.b4 writing to the streams i'm checking the stream if it exists or not.if it exists means i'm writing on that.otherwise i will create new stream.

Comment: In the example you're still only writing to the stream one time. Please show how you are going to writing to the stream multiple times to establish the context that `drain` can be used in.

Comment: How can I reproduce `writeOneMillionTimes`? Looks like it is not the code that would work after I paste it in my editor. It does not provide how `writer` is created.

Comment: @FreeLightman The `writer` is any instance of a writable stream. It can be inferred from how it must have a `write` method, and a `drain` event.

Comment: @hexacyanide I couldn't find function `once() ` in Node.js Stream API documents, [web]: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html/  Can I regard it as a `on()` function?

Answer (score 15):

Imagine you're connecting 2 streams with very different bandwidths, say, uploading a local file to a slow server. The (fast) file stream will emit data faster than the (slow) socket stream can consume it.

In this situation, node.js will keep data in memory until the slow stream gets a chance to process it. This can get problematic if the file is very large.

To avoid this, `Stream.write` returns `false` when the underlying system buffer is full. If you stop writing, the stream will later emit a `drain` event to indicate that the system buffer has emptied and it is appropriate to write again.

You can use `pause/resume` the readable stream and control the bandwidth of the readable stream.

Better: you can use `readable.pipe(writable)` which will do this for you.

**EDIT**: There's a bug in your code: regardless of what `write` returns, your data has been written. You don't need to retry it. In your case, you're writing `data` twice.

Something like this would work:

```
var packets = […],
    current = -1;

function niceWrite() {
  current += 1;

  if (current === packets.length)
    return stream.end();

  var nextPacket = packets[current],
      canContinue = stream.write(nextPacket);

  // wait until stream drains to continue
  if (!canContinue)
    stream.once('drain', niceWrite);
  else
    niceWrite();
}
```

Comment: In  stream.once('drain', niceWrite); can we replace, once with on?

Comment: Will this recursion introduce stack overflow if packets is very long?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a version with async/await

```js
const write = (writer, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (!writer.write(data)) {
      writer.once('drain', resolve)
    }
    else {
      resolve()
    }
  })
}

// usage
const run = async () => {
  const write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('...')
  const max = 1000000
  let current = 0
  while (current <= max) {
    await write(write_stream, current++)
  }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/stevenkaspar/509f792cbf1194f9fb05e7d60a1fbc73

Answer (score 2):

This is a speed-optimized version using Promises (async/await). The caller has to check if it gets a `promise` back and only in that case `await` has to be called. Doing await on each call can slow down the program by a factor of 3...

```js
const write = (writer, data) => {
    // return a promise only when we get a drain
    if (!writer.write(data)) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            writer.once('drain', resolve)
        })
    }
}

// usage
const run = async () => {
    const write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('...')
    const max = 1000000
    let current = 0
    while (current <= max) {
        const promise = write(write_stream, current++)
        // since drain happens rarely, awaiting each write call is really slow.
        if (promise) {
            // we got a drain event, therefore we wait
            await promise
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit. I'm calling write in a loop. Any suggestions to fix?

Comment: @VPaul your loop must be async and await the promise returned by write.