# Node JS createWriteStream memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, memory-leaks

I have a node js procedure that, after reading say 10K rows from a database table, writes the rows to a CSV file. The rows are successfully written to the CSV file, but afterwards the node js memory usage has increased substantially and never goes back down. I suspect I have a (large) memory leak in the following code but can't find it.

To write this code I took guidance from [How to use drain event of stream.Writable in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932488/how-can-i-use-the-drain-event-with-createwritestream-method-in-node-js) . The code is executing the "drain" clause, & there are not error messages, but the memory leak problem remains.

Any ideas on the cause of the memory leak?

```
exports.csv_export_ar = function(req, res)
{
  global.mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err,connection) {
  if(err)
      console.log( "Erge:Export:AR:Error:getConnection failed:%s", err );
  else {
      var call_proc = "call export_recent_core_events_ar(" + connection.escape(req.params.coreguid) + ");";

      connection.query( call_proc, function(err,the_data) {
          if(err) {
                console.error("Erge:CsvExport:AR:Error:Calling export_recent_core_events_ar:%s", err ); 
          }
          else {                  
                  var filename = '/tmp/export_ar_' + the_coreguid + '.csv';
                  var ws = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

                  ws.on('finish', function () {
                      console.log('Erge:Export:File has been written');
                    });

                  // Add this to ensure that the out.txt's file descriptor is closed in case of error.
                  ws.on('error', function(err) {
                    console.log('Erge:Export:Error:%s', err);
                    ws.end();
                  });

                  ws.write( 
                          'datetime,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,' +
                          'pin_state,mode_state,prov_battery,prov solar,prov grid,' + 
                          'use battery,use hwc,use other,' +
                          'battery charge,prov solar model,prov grid model,use grid model \r\n' );

                  var i = 0;
                  exportLines();

                  function exportLines() {
                    var ok = true;
                    do {
                      var the_row = the_data[0][i];
                      var the_line =
                          the_row.created_on  + ',' + 
                          the_row.a0 + ',' + the_row.a1 + ',' + the_row.a2 + ',' + the_row.a3 + ',' + 
                          the_row.a4 + ',' + the_row.a5 + ',' + the_row.a6 + ',' + the_row.a7 + ',' + 
                          the_row.pin_state + ',' + the_row.mode_state + ',' +  
                          the_row.wProvBatteryRaw + ',' + the_row.wProvSolarRaw + ',' + the_row.wProvGridRaw + ',' + 
                          the_row.wUseBatteryRaw + ',' + the_row.wUseHwcRaw + ',' + the_row.wUseOtherRaw + ',' +
                          the_row.battery_charge + ',' +
                          the_row.wProvSolarModel + ',' + the_row.wProvGridModel + ',' + the_row.wUseGridModel + 
                          ' \r\n';
                      ok = ws.write(the_line);
                      i++;
                    } while (i < the_data[0].length && ok);

                    if (i < the_data[0].length) {
                        // had to stop early!
                        // write some more once it drains. 
                        // If we don't wait for the drain event then the memory usage was increased
                        ws.once('drain', exportLines);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ws.end();           
                        ws = null;
                    }
                  }
              }
          }

          connection.release( );
      });
     }
   });
 };
```

Comment: In the if/else at the bottom of exportLines, in the case that the ws needs draining you are recursively calling exportLines. However once that callback finishes you are not returning to your original function and calling <code>ws.end()</code>

Comment: Thanks for the input. But as I understand the code, there is only one instance of ws shared across the recursive calls and ws.end() is called exactly once on this shared instance at an appropriate point in time. So the code seems good to me. Can you expand on your thinking?