# Node.js writable.write return false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, streamwriter, writable

I want to upload (stream) control the writing process. But the writing process always returns false. Large files upload process stops. The output of the code is as follows;

```
> Node app.js
> False
> False
> False
> False
```

What am I doing wrong?

My code;

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var readable = fs.createReadStream('read.mkv');
  var writable  = fs.createWriteStream('write.mkv');

  readable.on('data', function(chunk){

      var buffer = writable.write(chunk);

      if(!buffer){ // ----> Always false! Why????

        readable.pause();
      }
      console.log(buffer);
  });

  writable.on('drain', function(){

    readable.resume();
  });
}).listen(8090);
```

Comment: how do you know writable.write always returns  true? what error message/code do you get in large files? Also, can you try readable.pipe(writeable) to see if the same error is reproducible?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932488/how-can-i-use-the-drain-event-with-createwritestream-method-in-node-js

Answer (score 3):

I have modified your program to show more information about what is happening:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');

const readable = fs.createReadStream('read.mkv');
const writable  = fs.createWriteStream('write.mkv');

readable.on('data', function(chunk){
  var buffer = writable.write(chunk);

  if(!buffer){ // ----> Always false! Why????
    readable.pause();
  }
  console.log(buffer, chunk.length);
});

writable.on('drain', function(){
  readable.resume();
  console.log('drain');
});
```

Output:

```
$ node blah.js
false 65536
drain
false 65536
drain
false 65536
drain
true 8192
```

I also used a different sized file as the input, so I have one `true` at the end of my output. If I increased my `read.mkv`’s size by, e.g., `10000` bytes, the last line would read `false 18192`.

What is happening is that each chunk returned by `read()` is large enough that it causes the write stream to exceed its [`highWaterMark`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_constructor_new_stream_writable_options) which defaults to `16384` (assuming that the stream returned by [`fs.createWriteStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)). As you can see from the numbers in the output, each `read()` (err, each `'data'` event) produces `65536` bytes except for the last one. Since writing this amount of data to `writable` causes it to exceed its `highWaterMark`, that stream advises to wait for `'drain'` before proceeding.

So, simply, you always see `false` emitted because the `readable` stream produces such large chunks when reading. And I would expect that no longer seeing any logs indicates that the transfer has finished. But you would really need to register [`.on('end')`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) and [`.on('error')`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error_1) to figure that out.

For a simple case like this, it is really better to just use [`readable.pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options), like:

```
readable.pipe(writable);
```

This will automatically handle `'drain'` for you. It will even call `writable.end()` for you appropriately.

Note that `pipe()` will not call `writable.end()` if it encounters a read or write error. If you have a long running process which needs to be resilient against stream errors, you need to make sure to handle the errors and close the streams to prevent handle leaks if your program runs for long enough to hit the file descriptor limit.

## What `false` Means

Streams enable programs to scale to large amounts of data by processing it a chunk at a time rather than loading it all into memory. Streams may be organized into pipelines representing various transformations on the data before it is finally written out. When `write()` returns `false`, it is signaling that it has received enough data to keep it busy for a while. If you keep sending it chunks, it will continue accepting those chunks. However, its backlog of data will grow and start consuming more memory. If you ignore this return value and keep sending it data from a very large source, you may even cause the program to exhaust its address space and crash or get stuck. To keep your code scalable, you should respect the `false` return and wait for `'drain`' as you did in your code.

However, `false` does not mean anything bad has happened or that there is any error. In fact, in any scenario where the source stream is faster than the destination stream, this is expected to happen and is the way the streams API keeps things safe.